# Decomposing HPC applications (CPU, mem bandwidth, etc)

Tags: mpi, hpc

I am trying to find out how much time an MPI application spends in CPU frequency, memory bandwidth and communication. I have tried tools like Forge or Intel aps but none of them seems to give accurate %. Is there a way to do this?
For instance, according to Intel APS:
[image]

Does this mean that this application is 19% MPI bound, 30% memory bandwidth bound and 51% CPU bound?

Comment: If you mean that you want to find out how much time your application spends in each of those states, then say so.  If you mean something else, say so.  Right now it's not at all clear what an answer to your question would look like.

Comment: Arm Performance Reports should be pretty close

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Arm Forge includes CPU and mem. bandw. within the same group.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark rephrased now

Comment: If by "Intel aps" you mean VTune then why do you think it does not give accurate number? I think VTune is very accurate. The problem is in how to interpret the numbers....

Comment: @VictorEijkhout does VTune work on AMD?